# Is there a way to capture special key combinations outside of a textbox/input?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

There is an event listener on the document to listen for key presses, specifically for `CTRL + Z` and `CTRL + Y` combinations, but it somehow gives a weird character that is the same for both combinations (``).

Here is the code:

```js
let history = []
let step

let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    isDrawingMode: true
});

history.push(JSON.stringify(canvas));
step = 0

canvas.on("object:added", () => {
    if (step !== history.length-1) history = history.slice(0, step + 1);  // setting up for redo for later
    history.push(JSON.stringify(canvas));
    step++;
    console.log(step);
});

document.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
    console.log(event.key);
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        if (`${event.key}` === "" && step) {
            const content = history[step];
            canvas.loadFromJSON(content, () => canvas.renderAll());
            step--;
            console.log(step);
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way to correctly capture the key presses and do the rest accordingly?

(Also, the event listeners get triggered weirdly and the step grows more than it should, but the most important problem right now is capturing the events properly)

[Github repo](https://github.com/Konstei/drawing-board)

Comment: Don't use `keypress` event, it fires only when a printable characted is feeded, and it's also deprecated.

Comment: @Teemu then how should i do it? that's just how i leared it, i don't know of any other way or that there even was another way

Comment: Use [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) or [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event) instead.